# FB Prophet: How can I reduce Timeseries forecast error?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I am forecasting daily sales for Q4-2020 with daily data going far back to Jan 2017. Using FB Prophet for this purpose. My data has weekly, monthly and yearly seasonality. Typically forecast errors are low for immediate days/weeks into the future and then increase for periods beyond few weeks. In my case, I am noticing a weird issue where forecast error is initially low, then spikes around 20th day and drops. I do not have any additional regressors. Any ideas on what I could be missing?

```
#Measuring Forecast error using historical data
m = Prophet(changepoint_prior_scale=0.01,holidays_prior_scale = 30)
m.add_country_holidays(country_name='US')
m.add_seasonality(name = "monthly", period = 30.5, fourier_order=5)
m.fit(df)
cutoffs = pd.to_datetime(['2020-09-30'])
df_cv = cross_validation(m, cutoffs = cutoffs, horizon='46 days', parallel="processes")
df_p = performance_metrics(df_cv)
#Plotting Forecast error
fig= plot_cross_validation_metric(df_cv,metric = "mape",rolling_window=0.15)
```

Here is a plot of my forecast error:

[image: Forecast Error]

Comment: Is there any gaps in your data? https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/non-daily_data.html#data-with-regular-gaps

Comment: Nope. I don't have any gaps in my data.